# Is there any difference between igGrid('destroy') and igGridUpdating('destroy')? (Ignite UI 2013.2)

Tags: jquery-ui, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

Using Ignite UI 2013.2

The goal of the question is to get it right : Is the result from calling igGrid('destroy') or igGridUpdating('destroy') the same?

If I

1. get a grid which has Updating, Sorting, Selection and all kind of other features on it or a date picker or a combo
2. and then call the common jQuery UI method 'destroy' method

will I get the desired result of actual object/ui control destruction or I will get a memory leak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `igGridUpdating` is a feature of the `igGrid`. If you call `igGrid("destroy")` this will destroy the `igGrid` widget together with all instantiated features for this instance of the `igGrid`. If you call destroy on the `igGridUpdating`, then you will get only this feature destroyed.